# c++ unresolved externals, compile error, and arrays with strings

Tags: c++, string, function, parameters

So this is an assignment I've been given that I'm having trouble with. The basis of the assignment is for have an array of strings hold regions. These regions have accidents in them and we must display the amount of accidents in a region, the count of which is held in a parallel array. The display part I can do later, however, The errors I'm getting are:

```
LNK1120: 1 unresolved externals

LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "void __cdecl findLowest(int,int,class 
std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> >)" 
(?findLowest@@YAXHHV?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@@Z)
referenced in function _main
```

The last error being a non compile saying this file is not a valid file or does not exist.

I have included a link to what the assignment says in full because the instructions are too long to write it all out.
https://mega.co.nz/#!INQjXbiS!lYbQ4gBHmsPua1wv1aigeZ_6MqIxvor7YPCFv49-G0Q

Thanks for your help!

```
#include <stdafx.h>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

//Function prototypes
void findLowest(int, int, string);
int getNumAccidents(string);

int main(){

    const int NUM_REGIONS = 5;
    string regionNames[NUM_REGIONS] = { "North", "South", "East", "West", "Central" };
    int regionAccidents[NUM_REGIONS];

    for (int i = 0; i < NUM_REGIONS; i++){//Populates the accident array
        regionAccidents[i] = getNumAccidents(regionNames[i]);

        if (regionAccidents[i] < 0)//checks to see if there are any accidents counts lower than 0
            regionAccidents[i] = 0;

        findLowest(regionAccidents[i], NUM_REGIONS, regionNames[i]);
    }
}

int getNumAccidents(string region){

    return 5;

}

void findLowest(int regAccidents[], int arraySize, string regNames[]){
    int lowest = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i <= arraySize; i++){
        if (regAccidents[i] < regAccidents[i++])
            lowest = regAccidents[i++];
    }
}
```

Comment: `void findLowest(int, int, string);` is not the same as `void findLowest(int regAccidents[], int arraySize, string regNames[])`

Comment: Check the signature of your function, the signature of your declaration of 'findLowest' doesn't match your defintion.

Comment: You're not even using `regNames` in `findLowest`, which makes it hard to decide what type it should be. Probably easiest just to delete it.

Comment: @Luchian Grigore: So what about the findLowest? I'm getting a different error. C2664: 'void findLowest(int [],int,std::string [])' : cannot convert argument 1 from 'int' to 'int []'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are declaring a function `findLowest` with parameters `(int, int, string)`, but defining it later with `(int[], int, string[])`. Technically, these are different functions, so that the declared function is not found by the linker.

Simply fix the declaration at the top of your file to match the actual definition, then things should work.

Comment: So I changed it but now I'm getting this: C2664: 'void findLowest(int,int,std::string [])' : cannot convert argument 3 from 'std::string' to 'std::string []'

The code I changed was: void findLowest(int, int, string[]);

Comment: Right, you still have to fix the call to findLowest. It should be `findLowest(regionAccidents, NUM_REGIONS, regionNames);` instead of `findLowest(regionAccidents[i], NUM_REGIONS, regionNames[i]`. At least it should compile then. But there are some logic errors in findLowest that I'm leaving for you to find and learn from the experience, since it is an assignment and we're not here to do your assignments :-)

Comment: Thanks! I'm guessing it's the existence of the function call inside the for loop right? Because currently lowest would always end up being 0 due to updating every loop iteration. Although I do have a question about the getNumAccidents(string region) function. I'm confused as to how I get the number of accidents for that specific region. Do I also have to use the regionAccidents array as a parameter or change the type of function to a string? Because those are the only ways I can see returning the correct value.

Comment: No, the problem I had in mind is the way you increment i three times inside the loop in `findLowest`.